# Bivariate distributions for two correlated variables with the same marginal distributions?

Tags: distributions, correlation

Consider two non-independent random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$ with joint CDF $F_{X_1,X_2}(\cdot,\cdot)$. Suppose that the marginal distribution of each variable is equal to $F_X(\cdot)$ and that this function is absolutely continuous. Under these conditions, [Sklar's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Sklar%27s_theorem) tells us that:

$$F_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = C(F_X^{-1}(x_1),F_X^{-1} (x_2))$$

Where $C(\cdot,\cdot)$ is a copula function. My question is whether it is true that we can write assume always that:

$$F_{X_1,X_2}(x_1,x_2) = \hat{F}(x_1,x_2;\rho)$$

where $\hat{F}(x_1,x_2;\rho) = \hat{F}(x_2,x_1;\rho)$ and $\rho$ is the correlation between $X_1$ and $X_2$. In other words, if we know the correlation between two identically distributed variables, is their joint distribution fixed as a symmetric function of these variables? [An [inspection of the cases where we know how to compute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copula_(probability_theory)#Empirical_copulas) $F_{X_1,X_2}$ (for instance, Gaussian or exponential random variables) suggests that the answer is YES, but I am not sure this is the general case].